Updates to one-to-many / many-to-one relation with typeorm ends up setting to 'null' or doesn't update at all
I have looked through similar posts I could find but none of the solutions worked for me, perhaps i am doing something wrongly, which is why i am posting this for help.
Explaining the functionality
In a program, there are stages, tasks and checkpoints (all three have their own deadlines). A stage consists of multiple tasks and checkpoints, and sometimes, tasks can be linked to checkpoints.
Before now, you couldn't change the deadline of a stage in a flexible way, you had to move all the tasks and checkpoints (children) backwards if you wanted to move the deadline of the stage back. if not that will mean that they're not in that stage anymore.
These are what the relations look like:
@Entity()
class Program {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Stage, (stage) => stage.program)
  stages: Promise<Stage[]>;
}

@Entity()
class Stage {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Task, (task) => task.stage)
  tasks: Promise<Task[]>;

  @OneToOne(() => Checkpoint, (checkpoint) => checkpoint.stage, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  finalCheckpoint: Checkpoint;

  @OneToMany(() => Checkpoint, (checkpoint) => checkpoint.stage)
  intermediateCheckpoints: Promise<Checkpoint[]>;
}

@Entity()
class Checkpoint {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Stage, (stage) => stage.intermediateCheckpoints, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  stage: Stage;
}

@Entity()
class Task {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Stage, (stage) => stage.tasks, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  stage: Stage;

  @OneToOne(() => Checkpoint, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  checkpoint: Checkpoint;
}

What am i trying to achieve?
Well now i have made it possible to move a stage backwards or forwards past it's original boundaries, and that means the children can then be either moved to the next stage, or from the next stage, basically updating the stageId to the correct stage that falls within the new deadline.
Code
throughout this whole process, updateStage is called first:
export async function updateStage(
  transactionalEntityManager: EntityManager,
  programId: string,
  stageId: string,
  authInfo: AuthorizationInfoDto,
  req: StageUpdate,

) {
  const program = await retrieveProgram(transactionalEntityManager, programId);
  const stage = await retrieveStage(transactionalEntityManager, stageId, programId); // joins the tasks and checkpoints

  if (req.forceUpdateDeadline && req.deadline) {
    await moveStageChildrenWithoutLimits(
      transactionalEntityManager,
      program,
      stage,
      req.deadline,
    ); // move tasks and checkpoints to the appropriate stage
  }

    stage.deadline = req.deadline;

  const updatedStage = await transactionalEntityManager.save(stage);
  return await toStageDto(updatedStage, authInfo);
}

Here's the function that then moves the children:
async function moveStageChildrenWithoutLimits(
  transactionalEntityManager: EntityManager,
  program: Program,
  stage: Stage,
  newDeadlineReq: Date,
) {
  const stages = await program.stages;
  const stageNewDeadline = new Date(newDeadlineReq).getTime();
  const stageOldDeadline = new Date(stage.deadline).getTime();
  const stageIndex = stages.findIndex((s) => s.id === stage.id);

  // new deadline is before the old one
  if (stageNewDeadline < stageOldDeadline) {
    const tasks = await stage.tasks;
    const tasksToMove = tasks.filter(
      (task) => task.deadline.getTime() > stageNewDeadline,
    );
    const tasksToUnlink = tasks.filter(
      (task) =>
        task.deadline.getTime() < stageNewDeadline && task.checkpointId,
    );

    const intermediateCheckpoints = await stage.intermediateCheckpoints;
    const intermediateCheckpointsToMove = intermediateCheckpoints.filter(
      (checkpoint) =>
        checkpoint.deadline.getTime() > stageNewDeadline &&
        stage.finalCheckpoint.id !== checkpoint.id,
    );
    const nextStage = stages[stageIndex + 1];

    // move tasks to the next stage
    const taskPromises = tasksToMove.map(async (task) => {
      task.stage = nextStage;
      return transactionalEntityManager.getRepository(Task).save(task);
    });
    await Promise.all(taskPromises);

    // unlink tasks that will have checkpoints in the next stage
    const tasksUnlinked = tasksToUnlink.map(async (task) => {
      const linkedCheckpointRelevance = task.checkpointId;
      const checkpointRelevanceDB = await transactionalEntityManager
        .getRepository(CheckpointRelevance)
        .findOne({
          where: { id: linkedCheckpointRelevance },
          relations: ['checkpoint'],
        });

      const checkpointDeadline =
        checkpointRelevanceDB.checkpoint.deadline.getTime();
      if (checkpointDeadline > stageNewDeadline) {
        task.checkpoint = null;
        transactionalEntityManager
          .getRepository(CheckpointRelevance)
          .softDelete({
            id: linkedCheckpointRelevance,
          });
        return transactionalEntityManager
          .getRepository(Task)
          .save(task);
      }
    });
    await Promise.all(tasksUnlinked);

    //  move intermediate checkpoints to the next stage
    const checkpointPromises = intermediateCheckpointsToMove.map(
      async (checkpoint) => {
        checkpoint.stage = nextStage;
        await transactionalEntityManager
          .getRepository(Checkpoint)
          .save(checkpoint);
      },
    );
    await Promise.all(checkpointPromises);
  }

  //  new deadline is after current one
  if (stageNewDeadline > stageOldDeadline) {
    const nextStage = stages[stageIndex + 1];
    const tasks = await nextStage.tasks;
    const tasksToMove = tasks.filter(
      (task) => task.deadline.getTime() < stageNewDeadline,
    );
    const intermediateCheckpoints = await nextStage.intermediateCheckpoints;
    const intermediateCheckpointsToMove = intermediateCheckpoints.filter(
      (checkpoint) =>
        checkpoint.deadline.getTime() < stageNewDeadline &&
        nextStage.finalCheckpoint.id !== checkpoint.id,
    );

    const tasksPromise = tasksToMove.map(async (task) => {
      // PROBLEM HERE: these parts don't work
      task.stage = stage; // this sets the stageID to null in the db
      const linkedCheckpointRelevance = task.checkpointId;

      if (linkedCheckpointRelevance) {
        const checkpointRelevanceDB = await transactionalEntityManager
          .getRepository(CheckpointRelevance)
          .findOne({
            where: { id: linkedCheckpointRelevance },
            relations: ['checkpoint'],
          });

        const checkpointDeadline =
          checkpointRelevanceDB.checkpoint.deadline.getTime();
        if (checkpointDeadline > stageNewDeadline) {
          task.checkpoint = null;
          transactionalEntityManager
            .getRepository(CheckpointRelevance)
            .softDelete({
              id: linkedCheckpointRelevance,
            });
        }
      }
      return transactionalEntityManager.getRepository(Task).save(task);
    });
    await Promise.all(tasksPromise);

    const checkpointsPromise = intermediateCheckpointsToMove.map(
      async (checkpoint) => {
        checkpoint.stage = stage;
        return transactionalEntityManager
          .getRepository(Checkpoint)
          .save(checkpoint);
      },
    );
    await Promise.all(checkpointsPromise);
  }
}



what I have tried:
I have tried making the updates using the query builder, even using raw sql with the .query() method but to no avail, i tried one query directly on the db and it worked. I have also tried making the updates on the Stage entity itself, added new tasks to the next stage.
Versions

typeorm v0.3.20 (was 0.3.16 then upgraded)
postgres: v14.1 - alpine
node v18.16


Edit : I found the problem
I cannot believe the solution was this simple, but it was to save the stage without the children relations in the array because they've already been modified and saved, so saving the stage like that would overwrite it all.
 const updatedStage = await transactionalEntityManager.save(Stage, {deadline: stage.deadline});
// the other tasks[] and checkpoints[] have already been updated so no need to save it here again, else they will be overriden


